# Rails: Allow user to destroy votes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model, controller, destroy

So I have a pretty simple vote system that allow users to vote a pin:

**app/views/pins/show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to upvote_pin_path(@pin), method: :put, remote: true do %>
Upvote
<% end %>
```

**app/controller/pins_controller.rb**

```
 def upvote
  @pin = Pin.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @pin.votes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @pin }
    format.js
 end
end
```

**app/models/vote.rb**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :pin, counter_cache: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :pin_id, scope: :user_id
end
```

**config/routes**

```
  resources :pins do 
    resources :comments
    member do
    put 'upvote'
  end 
  end
```

What I want is to allow users to destroy their votes if they want to. I tried several things using a :delete and destroy method but nothing is working. Any ideas to put me on track ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a method in the model that checks if a vote for a given users exists, then delete it if it does, otherwise create one. Then in your controller, in the upvote method you've created, call the new method in the model.

Of course you could do all of that in the controller, but it's best if you don't.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how to do that, could you highlight this with a little bit of code to put me on track ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mwiley/a54abe86819c0b825532 This should get you mostly there, but I haven't tried this code.

You would probably want another method in the model that checks if a vote exists so you can update the view accordingly. This method in the model already does that, so all you need to do is move that part into its own method.